# Set value of div with contenteditable=true

Tags: javascript, html

Given a div with `contenteditable=true`, how can I add text to the element?

```
<div aria-autocomplete="list" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="true">

</div>
```

I've tried `document.activeElement.value`, but since it's a div I can't set the value

Comment: You have to use the innerHTML method.
element.innerHTML = "content" ;

For further information look to the doc.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/innertHTML

Answer (score 2):

With the other answers about `innerHTML`, I am afraid if `innerHTML` without sanitization might give attackers a chance to run unwanted malicious code.

I would rather go with `textContent` because the OP wants to add text.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content" aria-autocomplete="list" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="true">

</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
document.getElementById('content').textContent = 'My text';
```

If you want to render HTML tags too you need a sanitization callback to filter tags like **SCRIPT** tag as an example.

Comment: Could you tell me what the diference between running code in html page from running it at the browser console? (According vulnerablity)

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the innerHTML of the div. So for example:

```
document.activeElement.innerHTML = "Changed text";
```

You can also get the current contents of the div by getting the same property, for example:

```
alert("User entered text: " + document.activeElement.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

A React **ref** version answer of this question:

```
// set the init value to it
const initText = "123\n123123\n123123123";
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
useEffect(() => {
  if (ref && ref.current) {
    ref.current.innerText = initText;
  }
}, []);

const handleInput = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  console.log("input:", e.target.innerText);
};
```

notice that we are using **`innerText`** here,
for `innerHtml`, `textContent` they won't give a default line-change for `\n` with the code below

```
<div
  ref={ref}
  contentEditable={true}
  onInput={handleInput}
  style={{
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
    border: "1px solid black",
    display: "table-cell",
    verticalAlign: "middle",
    textAlign: "left",
    padding: 8
  }}
></div>
```

additionally, we can use CSS `:empty` to let the initial cursor keep at the vertical center as well

```
.InputField {
  height: 200px; // initial height, real size could auto increase
  ...
}
.InputField:empty {
  line-height: 200px; // the same initial height's value as above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best way to set the content is:

```
target.firstChild.data = "<some-new-value>";
```

..where the firstChild is the textNode.