# How to dynamically add content to an editable div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I would like to dynamically add content to an editable div.
The idea is:

1. Click on the input button
2. Select a file
3. Upload the file to the server
4. The server returns some data
5. Insert the returned data into an editable div at the left position before clicking the input button to select the uploaded file.
   This is my attempt, which does not work as expected.

```
<span class="">
<input type="file" class="input-file" id="input-file">file
</span>
<div contenteditable="true" class="div_edit" id="div_edit">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
</div>
```

```
$(document).on("change", ".input-file", function(e){
    upload_file();      
});

function upload_file(){
    var name = document.getElementById("input-file").files[0].name;  
  
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        method:"POST",
        data: {"name": name},
        beforeSend:function(){
            console.log("upload...");
        },
        success:function(data){
            var res = '<span class="span-added">' + data + '</span>';

            const elInsert = document.querySelector("#input-file");
            elInsert.addEventListener("click", () => {
                document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, res);
            });            
        }
    });   
    return;
}
```

Comment: From the description it seems like you're trying to ***read*** a file, not upload a file. If that's the case, the solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/750032/519413.

Comment: Not really @RoryMcCrossan. I would like to upload the file, then insert the returned data where I was in the editable div, before selecting the file.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191317/set-value-of-div-with-contenteditable-true

Comment: @Arashjahanbakhshan not really

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77894830/11857974 almost does that. The problem is that I have to click a button for it to work. In this case, I want it to be added after the file has been uploaded to the server.  added after the file has been uploaded to the server.

Answer (score 0):

`Document.execCommand()` method is depricated, use vanilla js instead

**ex:**

```js
function upload_file() {

    var name = document.getElementById("input-file").files[0].name;

    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function (data) {

            // don't concat data to string directly
            var res = '<span class="span-added">' + data.name + '</span>';

            const elInsert = document.querySelector("#input-file");
            const doc = document.querySelector(".div_edit")

            doc.innerHTML += res; // use vanilla js instead of execCommand()

        }
    });
    return;
}
```